# load ed25519 public key with java

Tags: python, java, signature, public-key, ed25519

I have to read and load ed25519 public key for verifying signature in java, the token input pattern is:
{public_key}/message.signature
for example:

```
6a3239269f93999baec60382189c718031ad22c4c807ff29417824132cf0aa2d/eyJpc3N1ZV9kYXRlIjogIjIwMjItMTAtMjMiLCAiZXhwaXJ5X2RhdGUiOiAiMjAyMi0xMS0yMyIsICJsaWNlbnNlX3R5cGUiOiAxLCAibGljZW5zZV9rZXkiOiAiOTczZTIxOWVlNDg5NDVlNmViMDhjYzQzM2QyYjBjMDUifQ==.122ff0664a54122c6929183a561bb211a4168801e5917f33b69231eea56205ae32af4804a69a9fd25c6fab4bbf44048b57b11d71c5b8fe4fb153d0f45c5e140f
```

This token created via python library 'ed25519':

```
private_key, public_key = ed25519.create_keypair()
public_key_string = public_key.to_ascii(encoding='hex').decode('utf-8')
signature = private_key.sign(json_string.encode('utf-8'), encoding='hex')
token = public_key_string + '/' +
                        base64.b64encode(json_string.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8') +
                        '.' + signature.decode('utf-8')
```

When Im trying to split the token into parts in java and load the public key (with bouncycastle library), exception have been thrown and said that the buffer must be 32 length (which as you can see the length of the public key is 64), what am I missing here?

Comment: `token` is a concatenation of the hex encoded raw public key, the Base64 encoded message and the hex encoded signature, where `/` separates the key and message parts and `.` separates the message and signature parts. The error message indicates that (at least) the encoding of the key was not taken into account when separating. Please post your most recent Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The public key encoded as hexadecimals, and then encoded using base64. To revert this incorrect way of encoding you'd first need to decode the base64 and then decode the hexadecimals to bytes. To fix the python script instead, perform `base64.b64encode(public_key.to_bytes()` and remove the `public_key_string`.

It seems weird that the public key is base 64 & hex encoded and why the signature is only hex encoded. It makes most sense to encode both using base64, if any textual output is required at all. Quite often text is used where binary could suffice just as well.

Comment: Great! Hope it didn't take you 13 days of debugging ;)

Comment: lol no, just delayed response =]